# Into a single query

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have got a table

```
 unam     fnam

 john     alex
 alex     john
```

I want a query that returns true if unam 'john' == fnam 'alex' or unam 'alex' == fname 'john'

I dont know how to do it in a single query . 
My code

```
$re = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE unam='john' and fnam='alex' LIMIT 1"); 
$ir = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE unam='alex' and fnam='john' LIMIT 1"); 

if ((!(mysql_num_rows($re))) && (!(mysql_num_rows($ir)))) echo 'not exists';
```

I have executed 2 seperate queries (one for `unam 'john' == fnam 'alex'` and other for `unam 'alex' == fname 'john'`,  if both the queries do not have any rows it echos not exists.

I was thinking may be it can be optimized to a single query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do an OR conditional to check for multiple different conditions.

```
SELECT 1 
FROM tab 
WHERE (unam='john' and fnam='alex') 
    OR (fnam='john' and unam='alex') 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put your logic in the `where` clause like this:

```
select 1
from tab
where (uname = 'john' and fname = 'alex') or
      (fname = 'alex' and uname = 'john')
limit 1
```

By the way, if you want to always return a value, say `0` or `1`, you can use aggregation:

```
select coalesce(max(1), 0) as retval
from tab
where (uname = 'john' and fname = 'alex') or
      (fname = 'alex' and uname = 'john')
```

If no rows are selected, then the `max()` returns `NULL` which the `coalesce()` turns into `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **OR** statement to achieve this.

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT 1 
FROM tab 
WHERE 
(unam='john' and fnam='alex') 
OR 
(unam='alex' and fnam='john')
limit 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$re = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab WHERE (unam='john' and fnam='alex') OR (unam='alex' and fnam='john')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a different approach, using EXISTS, and a different syntax:

```
SELECT
  EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM names
          WHERE (unam, fnam) IN (('john', 'alex'),('alex','john')))
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12def/3).